# How to get a tenure of a client with different start end dates?

Tags: sql, sas

[image]

Hey Guys!

Just wondering how to calculate the time a client spends.
As you can see, there were some gaps that this client was not holding any policy. I would like to take those gap time out of my equation.
I am using

```
proc sql;
create table client_lost as 
select distinct party_id,
max(end_date) as max_end_date format date9.,
min(START_DATE) as min_start_date format date9.
group by 1
;quit;

data client_lost_2;
set client_lost;
tenure = yrdif(min_start_date,max_end_date,'Actual'); 
run;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SAS, but it seems like a better approach would be to calculate the "tenure" of each policy individually, then add all of those up for the total, rather than finding the difference between the max and min and then subtracting out the gaps.

Comment: that's a good idea, but some policies have overlap time which should also be eliminated. if i just calculate the tenure individually and add them up. it will create double counting

Comment: This is an "Islands and Gaps" problem discussed in other questions -- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=island+and+gap

Comment: Please post data as text, not as an image, if anyone wanted to test your code or a solution that would mean typing out your data. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Determine-coverage-periods-for-data-with-gaps-and-overlaps/m-p/277697/highlight/true#M55784

Comment: And please don't start your questions as 'guys' unless you only want guys to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looking at data that follows a linear type order and order is important, using a data step is a better approach.

First sort your data, and then use a DoW loop to go through and identify each gap and continuous period of coverage. Once that's done, you can calculate the difference and sum them. Another option, if your data is small is to create a 'daily' file which creates a record for each date, you remove duplicates and then can re-summarize as needed for continuous intervals and gaps. But it's more code and longer.

Replace the variable names below with yours and you should be fine to get the periods corrected.

ID = client_id
ProductNumber = Policy_ID
EffectiveDate = Start_Date
ExpiryDate = End_Date

```
proc sort data=prod; 
by ID ProductNumber EffectiveDate descending ExpiryDate; 
run;

data align_periods;
do until(last.productNumber);
    set prod; by id productNumber;
    format effD expD yymmdd10.;
    if expD < effectiveDate then
        if not missing(expD) then do;
             output;
             call missing(effD, expD);
             end;
    effD = min(effD, effectiveDate);
    expD = max(expD, expiryDate);
    duration = expD - effD;
    end;
output;
drop effectiveDate expiryDate;
rename effD=effectiveDate expD=expiryDate;
run;

proc means data=align_periods noprint;
class ID;
var duration;
output out=want sum(duration) = tenure;
run;
```